# Call 3rd-party assembly's overloaded method from generic method using dynamic (or by other means)?

Tags: c#, generics, dispatch, overload-resolution

**Update: Turns out there were details I had completely missed until I looked at the source code of the library I was using.  Apologies for the bad example code starting out, was trying to focus on what I thought was relevant.**

Working with FlatFiles NuGet library which has 25 overloads for a `Property(...)` method.  I'm trying to dispatch the correct `Property(...)` overload from my generic method by using dynamic on a parameter I'm passing, but this isn't working.  Here's what I tried:

```
using FlatFiles;
using FlatFiles.TypeMapping;

public class FixedWidthDataSource<FixedWidthRecordT> {
    public IFixedLengthTypeMapper<FixedWidthRecordT> Mapper
        = FixedLengthTypeMapper.Define<FixedWidthRecordT>()
    ;
    ...
    public void MapProperty<T>(
        Expression<Func<FixedWidthRecordT, T>> col
        , int width
        , string inputFormat = null
    ) {
        var window = new Window(width);
        Mapper.Property((dynamic)col, window);
    }
}

public class FixedWidthRecord
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}

//later
var fwds = new FixedWidthDataSource<FixedWidthRecord>();
fwds.MapProperty(c=>c.First, 5);
```

A few of the Property overloads:

```
Property(Expression<Func<FixedWidthRecordT, bool>> property, Window window);
Property(Expression<Func<FixedWidthRecordT, int>> property, Window window);
Property(Expression<Func<FixedWidthRecordT, string>> property, Window window);
```

The error I get is `'FlatFiles.TypeMapping.IFixedLengthTypeMapper<FixedWidthRecord>' does not contain a definition for 'Property'`.

Looking at the source I see the there's an
`internal sealed class FixedLengthTypeMapper<TEntity>`
and this is the type of object that's being returned from the call to `FixedLengthTypeMapper.Define<FixedWidthRecordT>()` and assigned to `Mapper`.  However, `IFixedLengthTypeMapper` does not have any definitions for `Property(...)`, only `FixedLengthTypeMapper` has them.

Hoping that's all relevant.

Comment: We'll need to see at least a couple different overloads of `Mapper.Property()` to properly solve this.

Comment: Focus on the error message.  `'Mapper<FixedWidthRecord>' does not contain a definition for 'Property'`.  Obviously we can't help you any more than that error message with the information you have provided.

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a short but complete example of what *doesn't* work.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got a complete example there.  I didn't copy/paste the code directly, hence the lack of a full example at first.  Apologies.

Comment: Is that the full error? And is it at compile time?

Comment: Yes, and I get that error at runtime.

Comment: When you say "3rd party flat file library" what do you mean? I made some similar overloads (`Expression<Func<T>>`) and it worked fine. Is it in another assembly? If it's possible to share a compiling repro, that would be fantastic.

Comment: I wrote out what I think is a very accurate attempt to repro, and it worked fine: [http://ideone.com/WHh1oK](http://ideone.com/WHh1oK).

Comment: Correct, it is in another assembly.

Comment: No repro here, even after moving `Foo<T>` into another assembly.

Comment: Do all the overloaded methods have the same parameter names? If not you try explicitly calling the parameter names to select the overload in question.

Comment: Yes, parameter names are the same.  Also, If I remove `dynamic`, I get "...best overload for method match... has some invalid arguments" and "cannot convert from 'Expression<Func<FixedWidthRecordT,T>>' to 'Expression<Func<FixedWidthRecordT,bool>>'" which is the type of the first paramter of the first overload.

Comment: Can you call the methods at all without the generic wrapper? Maybe you are compiling against one DLL and running against another that doesn't have any `Property(...)` definitions.

Comment: Yes, the methods can be called without the wrapper.  I updated my example code earlier today, not sure if that will clarify.

Comment: I think you might be wrong about `IFixedLengthTypeMapper<T>`: it inherits from `IFixedLengthTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` [which contains `Property` methods](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/FlatFiles/blob/master/FlatFiles/TypeMapping/FixedLengthTypeMapper.cs#L62).

Comment: Yeah I noticed that.  I can get things working by using IFixedLengthTypeConfiguration instance, so I guess in this case I'm good.  But the question still stands, how to dispatch from a generic method to the overloaded inherited methods of an interface instance when the interface is specified as internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I finally did to get it working, although it's by using an interface not described in the library's usage documentation.  I'm still curious how this could have otherwise been solved (say for instance, if the IFixedLengthTypeConfiguration interface I'm using in the solution were also defined as internal).

```
using FlatFiles;
using FlatFiles.TypeMapping;

public class FixedWidthDataSource<FixedWidthRecordT> {
    public IFixedLengthTypeConfiguration<FixedWidthRecordT> Configuration
        = FixedLengthTypeMapper.Define<FixedWidthRecordT>()
    ;
    public IFixedLengthTypeMapper<FixedWidthRecordT> Mapper;
    public FixedWidthDataSource() {
        Mapper = (IFixedLengthTypeMapper<FixedWidthRecordT>)Configuration;
    }
    ...
    public void MapProperty<T>(
        Expression<Func<FixedWidthRecordT, T>> col
        , int width
        , string inputFormat = null
    ) {
        var window = new Window(width);
        Configuration.Property((dynamic)col, window);
    }
}

public class FixedWidthRecord
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}

//later
var fwds = new FixedWidthDataSource<FixedWidthRecord>();
fwds.MapProperty(c=>c.First, 5);
```

Comment: Well, it's not that [the interface](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/FlatFiles/blob/master/FlatFiles/TypeMapping/FixedLengthTypeMapper.cs#L275) was internal, right? Maybe the specific thing that's happening is that "When referring to an internal class by an interface, <exception> is thrown when I try to use methods declared in the interface's ancestors." If that's accurate and you can make a standalone repro, I think that would be great for another question. (Maybe one of the C# heroes will pick it up.) Nice fix, btw, don't know if I would have thought to try it. :)

Comment: I think you're right, although I'm interested to know if it's caused by the combination of `IFixedLengthTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` being an ancestor interface and `FixedLengthTypeMapper<TEntity>` being internal, or either individually.  I probably will post a separate question on that once I can reproduce the issue.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm very interested in that too, academically. I'll keep an eye out for a follow-up, and maybe if I get a chance later this week I'll try modifying my repro. I wasn't actually aware you could even dispatch from a generic to a set of overloads with `dynamic` before I saw this question! Currently I use reflection and expression compilation to do this speedily, but now I have another thing I need to test perf against. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your case has something to do with this? [RuntimeBinderException – “does not contain a definition for”](http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2013/05/14/runtimebinderexception-does-not-contain-a-definition-for/).

That article gets that exception in the case of an anonymous object, but your case seems similar. Your assembly is trying to access something through `dynamic` it cannot normally see: an `internal` class in your case, an anonymous type in theirs.

Adding the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Your.Assembly")]` attribute on the library doesn't sound like a good option, but if you can build from source it could help temporarily. Or maybe with that info you could create a solid repro.

Comment: I did try a few different things and encountered the issues you describe, but nothing seemed to work.  I considered just compiling from source with the assembly declaration as well, but now that I can just use the other interface I'd rather not.